# Prove that the conditional distribution of a normal random variable is also normal random

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

How to prove the claim that the conditional distribution of a normal random variable is also normal random? And how to think it intuitively?

Comment: The duplicate addresses the question about intuition.  It also shows one way one might prove this claim generally.  However, a much simpler way is available: simply inspect the density function.  (This is a one-line proof.)

Comment: @whuber The link is about bivariate normal distribution. Is there an easier way to think about the simplest case that conditional larger or smaller than a constant? I.e. why is a one-sided truncated normal distribution still "normal"?

Comment: I don't follow, because truncated Normal distributions are not Normal, nor are they the same as conditional distributions.

Comment: @whuber I find I misunderstand the very basic definition of conditional distribution. Thank you very much for your reply to make me realize that.